# Plots created by figure function in just one window

Tags: matlab

i'm with these 3 plots generated by the figure function and 1 plot by rlocus and what i'm trying to do is to put these 4 plots in the same window, like subplot function does. I tried to use it but it didn't work and also i prefer to use figure function rather than plot function because of the default properties, so now i'm searching for some alternatives. Thanks in advance.

```
num1=1;
den1=[1,3,3,1];
G=tf(num1,den1);
for Kp=[0.1:0.1:1]
    G_c=feedback(Kp*G,1);
    step(G_c);
    hold on
end
figure

Kp=1; 
s=tf('s');
for Ti=[0.7:0.1:1.5]
    Gc=Kp*(1+1/Ti/s); 
    G_c=feedback(G*Gc,1); 
    step(G_c); 
    hold on
end
figure

Ti=1; 
s=tf('s');
for Td=[0.1:0.2:2]
    Gc=Kp*(1+1/Ti/s+Td*s); 
    G_c=feedback(G*Gc,1); 
    step(G_c); 
    hold on
end
figure
rlocus(G,[0,15])
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide more info than "it didn't work" and what other properties you were unsatisfied with when using `subplot` because otherwise we have no idea why you can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by you prefer figure function to plot function. My understanding is that plot uses the active or referenced figure. If you want multiple graphs in a window this is what `subplot` does.

Is this not what you want:
[image: Graphs displayed with subplot]

Using subplot:

```
subplot(2,2,1)
num1=1;
den1=[1,3,3,1];
G=tf(num1,den1);
for Kp=[0.1:0.1:1]
    G_c=feedback(Kp*G,1);
    step(G_c);
    hold on
end

subplot(2,2,2)
Kp=1; 
s=tf('s');
for Ti=[0.7:0.1:1.5]
    Gc=Kp*(1+1/Ti/s); 
    G_c=feedback(G*Gc,1); 
    step(G_c); 
    hold on
end

subplot(2,2,3)
Ti=1; 
s=tf('s');
for Td=[0.1:0.2:2]
    Gc=Kp*(1+1/Ti/s+Td*s); 
    G_c=feedback(G*Gc,1); 
    step(G_c); 
    hold on
end

subplot(2,2,4)
rlocus(G,[0,15])
```

Comment: yeah it was this, i was using the subplot function in the wrong way. Thak you very much for the help.